# NodeJS API App - Unable to display backend images in a browser - "The user is not authorized"

Tags: node.js

I have created a NodeJS backend api used to serve up a number of shop products. If I add the path of a saved imagine into the browser address bar (e.g. 'http://localhost:3000/public/upload/0C1D7F7C-42B1-4A62-B4C3-A042BEB6A6B5.jpg-1604606693142.jpeg') I can not view the saved image in the browser, I get the following error - "The user is not authorized".

The path to the backend image folder is this - public/uploads

The path to the folder should not require any authorization because I added an entry to the 'public/uploads' folder in my 'jwt.js'. See 'jwt.js' file below:-

```
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');

function authJwt() {
    const secret = process.env.secret;
    const api = process.env.API_URL;
    return expressJwt({
        secret,
        algorithms: ['HS256'],
        isRevoked: isRevoked
    }).unless({
        path: [
            { url: /\/public\/uploads(.*)/, methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS'] },
            { url: /\/api\/v1\/products(.*)/, methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS'] },
            { url: /\/api\/v1\/categories(.*)/, methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS'] },
            { url: /\/api\/v1\/orders(.*)/, methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST'] },
            `${api}/users/login`,
            `${api}/users/register`
            // { url: /(.*)/ },
        ]
    });
}

async function isRevoked(req, payload, done) {
    if (!payload.isAdmin) {
        done(null, true);
    }

    done();
}

module.exports = authJwt;
```

This is my 'app.js' file:-

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
require("dotenv/config");
const authJwt = require("./helpers/jwt");
const errorHandler = require("./helpers/error-handler");
const swaggerJsDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const router = express.Router();


const options = {
    swaggerDefinition: {
        openapi: "3.0.0",
        info: {
            title: "Libray API",
            version: "1.0.0",
            description: "A simple Express Library API"
        },
        servers: [
            {
                url: "http://localhost:3000"
            }
        ],
    },
    apis: ["./routes/*.js"]
}

const specs = swaggerJsDoc(options);
app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(specs));


// Cors
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());


// Middleware - for dealing with JSON objects posted from the frontend
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(authJwt());
app.use("/public/uploads", express.static(__dirname + "/public/uploads"));
app.use(errorHandler);


//Routes
const categoriesRoutes = require('./routes/categories');
const productsRoutes = require('./routes/products');
const usersRoutes = require('./routes/users');
const ordersRoutes = require('./routes/orders');

const api = process.env.API_URL;

app.use(`${api}/categories`, categoriesRoutes);
app.use(`${api}/products`, productsRoutes);
app.use(`${api}/users`, usersRoutes);
app.use(`${api}/orders`, ordersRoutes);


// Connection to MongoDB database
mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_STRING, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    dbName: 'eshop-database'
})
.then(() => {
    console.log('Database connection is ready');
})
.catch((err)=> {
    console.log(err);
})


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running http://localhost:3000');
})
```

Below is a screen shot showing my NodeJS project structure:-

[image]

Below is the error I see in the browser console:-

[image]

Can anyone help please?

Comment: If its saying that, then your regex may not be hitting in the unless, what happens if you try something like /^\/public\/uploads\/.*/  Also, just as a side note and more from a design perspective, if you plan for this to be a production api, then you should think about moving your uploads to some kind of object storage, this way you can scale the api, otherwise its always using ephemeral storage so you are locked to one server

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation proxim0. I tried what you suggested but I get the same error - 401 "The user is not authorized". This was the line I added - { url: /^\/public\/uploads\/.*/, methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS'] },

Comment: Looking at the error message you posted from the console, could it be file level permissions on that folder? Is this running locally or on a server, also what are the read / write permissions on that folder

Comment: The folder is on my local machine. The folder has read/write permissions for a groups and users set to "Allow".

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a path to the static files like that:

```
const path = require("path");

app.use("/public/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public/uploads")))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should swap this 2 lines with each other:

```
app.use(authJwt());
app.use("/public/uploads", express.static(__dirname + "/public/uploads"));
```

To

```
app.use("/public/uploads", express.static(__dirname + "/public/uploads"));
app.use(authJwt());
```

Comment: Hi Iamtacvu. Sorry I tried what you suggested, but it didnt work.